# WPF Style to automatically bind to base class property

Tags: wpf, binding

Good evening. A WFP binding question please.

Let's say that I have the following three classes:

```
public class Field
{
   public string Data {get; set; }
   public string TooltipText {get; set; }

   public Field(string data, string tttext)
   {
      Data = data;
      TooltipText = tttext;
   }
}

public class FName : Field
{
   public FName()
      : base("","Enter first name")
   {
   }
}

public class Person
{
   public FName FirstName {get; set; }
}
```

In XAML, assuming I have set the data context to Person in code, I can bind a TextBox's text and tooltip by

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName.Data, Mode=TwoWay}" Tooltip={Binding FirstName.TooltipText}" />
```

Is there a way to do this generically (if that's the first word) by referencing the base class' properties in a style so that I do not need to declare it for every TextBox? For instance, as a mockup:

```
<TextBox Binding="FirstName" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}">
```

and the style is something like

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetStyle="TextBox">
   <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Field.Data, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   <Setter Property="Tooltip" Value="{Binding Field.TooltipText}" />
</Style>
```

All of my input fields are derived from a base class and it would be nice for the binding of data and tooltips to occur automatically from the Style.

Thank you in advance for any knowledge and/or help along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted will work fine, just bind directly to `Data` and `TooltipText` instead of `Field.Data` and `Field.TooltipText`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, which is exactly what you replied! I just need to set the DataContext to FieldName and now it all works perfectly.

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" DataContext={Binding FirstName}">
```

This data-binding stuff is so cool.

Thanks again for the help!